# Grouping in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to get the top touristCount in each month like January Zambia has 4 touristCount i need to select only Zambia for January and so on

```sql
    user
     `useri_id` |  `username`   | `email` | `nationality`
      1             Joseph           ``       US
      2             Abraham.         ``       UK
      3             g.wood           ''       Zambia
      4             Messi.           ''       France
      5             Ronaldo.         ''       Namibia
      6             Pogba.           ''       Holand.

    bookings
       booking_id   |  user_id   | booking_date | tour_id
        1                1           2022-01-01       1
        2                1           2022-01-01       6
        3                1           2022-05-01       2
        4                3           2022-01-01       5
        5                2           2022-04-01       5
        6                2           2022-11-01       7
        7                3           2022-12-01       2
        8                6           2022-01-01       1
```

this is what i have tried

```sql
SELECT s.nationality AS Nationality,
COUNT(b.tourist_id) AS touristsCount,
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(b.booked_date, '%d-%m-%Y')) AS `MonthNumber`
FROM bookings b, users s
WHERE s.user_id = b.tourist_id
AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(b.booked_date, '%d-%m-%Y')) = '2022'
GROUP BY Nationality,MonthNumber
order BY MonthNumber ASC
LIMIT 100
```

i need the results to be like

```
nationality    |     TouritIdCount   |      MonthNumber
  US                       2                     01
  UK                       1                     04
  US                       1                     05
  UK                       1                     11
  ZAMBIA                   1                     12
```

Comment: What does `select version():;` show?

Comment: 10.4.21-MariaDB @ysth

Comment: Is booking_date a string or a date?  If a string, what format is it in?

Comment: its date format yyy-mm-dd

Comment: Really? You store dates as strings? Why??? And you say the format is 'yyy-mm-dd', but you are trying to convert it according to the '%d-%m-%Y' format? That doesn't seem to make any sense. Then the year function results in an integer value; why are you comparing it to a string ('2022')? Then, who taught you joins that got out-dated long before MariaDB even existed? Use explicit joins (`[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, etc.) as defined in the SQL standard since 1992. Then, what to do, if two or more users have the same top count in a month?

Comment: In your sample data there is just one user per country. Is this guaranteed to be the case in your reall database, too? Or can there be more users per country?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner just forget about my sql, i just tried doesnt mean its right, anyway just focus to provide the solution if you have one....yes there are more users with the same country

Comment: @google009665 a more sensibly structured query (and schema if you can change it) seem likely to be of tremendous additional benefit to both you and the community and may be the roots of why your Question could be difficult or difficult to Answer (it may not be directly relevant here, but you may enjoy [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT nationality, COUNT(booking_id) AS TouristIdCount, MONTH(booking_date) AS MonthNumber
FROM users u
JOIN bookings b ON u.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE YEAR(booking_date) = 2022
GROUP BY nationality, MonthNumber
ORDER BY TouristIdCount DESC, MonthNumber ASC
```

Comment: your commands will select everything by month, what i need is to select the only country that has more count like for January US has 2 counts, Zambia has 1 count and Holand has one so i need to display only US because it has 2 counts.

Comment: @Ishak Hari: A general remark: While your query looks much better than the original, don't post code-only answers. Describe which issues you have addressed in your query and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
having COUNT(b.tourist_id) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to count bookings per month and tourist's nationality and then show only the top nationality (or nationalities) per month.

There are two very similar approaches:

1. Rank the nationalities' booking counts per month with `RANK` and only show the best ranked rows.
2. Select the top booking count per month and only show rows matching their top count.

The following query uses the second method. It shows one row per month and top booking nationality. Often there may be excatly one row for a month showing the one top booking nationality, but there may also be months where nationalities tie and share the same top booking count, in which case we see more than one row for a month.

```
select year, month, nationality, booking_count
from
(
  select
    year(b.booking_date) as year,
    month(b.booking_date) as month,
    u.nationality,
    count(*) as booking_count,
    max(count(*)) over (partition by year(b.booking_date), month(b.booking_date)) as months_max_booking_count
  from bookings b
  join users u on u.user_id = b.tourist_id
  group by year(b.booking_date), month(b.booking_date), u.nationality
) ranked
where booking_count = months_max_booking_count
order by year, month, nationality;
```

As your own sample data doesn't contain any edge cases, here is some other sample data along with my query's result and an explanation. (In other words, this is what you should have shown in your request ideally.)

### users

| user_id | username | email | nationality |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joseph | joseph@mail.us | US |
| 2 | Mary | mary@mail.us | US |
| 3 | Abraham | abraham@mail.uk | UK |

### bookings

| booking_id | user_id | booking_date | tour_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-11 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-01-11 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022-01-11 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 2022-01-22 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 2022-05-01 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 | 2022-05-01 | 3 |
| 7 | 1 | 2022-05-12 | 4 |
| 8 | 2 | 2022-05-12 | 4 |
| 9 | 3 | 2022-05-14 | 5 |
| 10 | 3 | 2022-05-20 | 6 |
| 11 | 3 | 2022-05-27 | 7 |

### result

| year | month | nationality | booking_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | UK | 2 |
| 2022 | 1 | US | 2 |
| 2022 | 5 | US | 4 |

In January there were two tours, but we are not interested in tours. We see four bookings, two by the Americans, two by the Britsh person. This is a tie, and we show two rows, one for UK and one for US with two bookings each.

In May there were five tours, but again, we are not interested in tours. There are seven bookings, four by the Americans, three by the Britsh person. So we only show US as the top country with four bookings here.